# jupyterLab でPILライブラリを使用した際に取り込んだ画像のインライン表示ができない。

Tags: python3, docker, pytorch, jupyter-lab, pillow

マイナビ出版から出ている「PyTorch実践入門」を進めるにあたり下記の問題が発生しました。
本書の推奨環境はJupyterとなっている為、DockerHubから以下をpullしています。

```
% docker run --rm -d -v $PWD:/app -p 8888:8888 \pman0214/pytorch_jupyterlab:1.9.0
```

runコマンド引用サイト

[M1 macな人たちに贈るpytorch+jupyterlab docker image](https://qiita.com/pman0214/items/ec2c6831af67ecb3eb04)

参考書に沿って以下を実行し、

```
from torchvision import models
alexnet = models.alexnet()
resnet = models.resnet101(pretrained=True)

from torchvision import transforms
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256)
    ,transforms.CenterCrop(224)
    ,transforms.ToTensor()
    ,transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0,406]
        ,std=[0.229, 0,224, 0.225]
    )])
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("data/bobby.jpeg")
img
```

imgを呼び出すとフォルダに格納されている犬の画像が表示されてしまいます。
求める挙動としてはインラインで

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1280x720 at 0xFFFF65190E80>
```

と表示させたいです。（上記のインライン表示は”print(img)”で出力しています。）
というのも、以下を実行すると

```
img_t = preprocess(img)
```

文字列がないのでエラーとして返されるためです。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-5823a1581b62> in <module>
----> 1 img_t = preprocess(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
     58     def __call__(self, img):
     59         for t in self.transforms:
---> 60             img = t(img)
     61         return img
     62 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in forward(self, tensor)
    219             Tensor: Normalized Tensor image.
    220         """
--> 221         return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)
    222 
    223     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in normalize(tensor, mean, std, inplace)
    328     std = torch.as_tensor(std, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
    329     if (std == 0).any():
--> 330         raise ValueError('std evaluated to zero after conversion to {}, leading to division by zero.'.format(dtype))
    331     if mean.ndim == 1:
    332         mean = mean.view(-1, 1, 1)

ValueError: std evaluated to zero after conversion to torch.float32, leading to division by zero.
```

さまざまサイトを調べましたが、参考書同様に

```
img
```

を実行すればインラインが、

```
img.show()
```

で画像が表示される。
とあり、今回の挙動のような例が見つかりませんでした。
jupyterLab側の設定なのか、そもそもコードが間違っているのか見当がつかないため
知恵をお貸しください。

ちなみに、`img.show()` を実行しても特に何も起こりませんでした。
また、 google colaboratoryで実行しても同様の挙動を確認しています。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「参考書」とは何でしょう？ それにはJupyter(Lab/Notebook)を使って行うと書いてありますか？ 参考書に書かれているという内容は、Jupyterでは無く CUI のPythonインタプリタ上での動作と思われます。googlecolaboratoryもJupyterなので実質的な環境は変わりません。そうした動作環境を参考書と違うもので行っている可能性が考えられます。

Comment: 今回使用している参考書はマイナビ出版から出ている「PyTorch実践入門」です。本書の推奨環境はJupyterです。説明不足でした。

Comment: そうすると推奨環境と説明が合っていない感じですね。表示されるはず、と書かれている内容はJupyterではなくCUIのPythonインタプリタでの動作と同じに見えます。必ずしもすべての説明がJupyterでの操作や結果に沿っているのではないかもしれません。試しにCUIのPythonインタプリタ環境で動かしてみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはその記述が何ページの何処にあると追記すれば、同じ参考書の所持者から何かしらの助言や回答があるかもしれません。

Comment: ```
# python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 28 2021, 10:21:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 +2
3
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open("data/bobby.jpeg")
>>> img
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1280x720 at 0xFFFF871E4D60>
>>>
```
CUIで動かしてみました。
これだとうまくいきますね・・・

Comment: こんなリポジトリがあるようですが、質問に合ったものでしょうか？ [Gin5050/deep-learning-with-pytorch-ja](https://github.com/Gin5050/deep-learning-with-pytorch-ja), [deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code)

Comment: ありがとうございます！質問できるコーナーもあるみたいなのでそちらにも投げてみます！

Answer (score 0):

当該事象について解決しましたので、顛末を書かせていただきます。

**問題箇所**

以下の `mean, std` に代入される配列の小数点とカンマを混同して記述しておりました。

```
mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0,406]
,std=[0.229, 0,224, 0.225]
```

正しくは以下のような記述になります。初歩的なミスでした。

```
mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
```

また、インライン表示ができない旨の質問をさせて頂きましたが、本書の[リポジトリ内](https://github.com/Gin5050/deep-learning-with-pytorch-ja/blob/main/p1ch2/2_pre_trained_networks.ipynb)でも同様の挙動をしており仕様であると考えられます（問題が解決したので詳細調査は行いませんでした）。

今回コメントを頂きました kunif様 ご協力いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 「インライン表示」の意味が違う気がします。(なので何を質問してたか不明だった)。「インライン表示」のワード使わずに説明したほうがいいかもです。(本来は, 別ウィンドウで表示したりすること無く, 出力に埋め込むような表示のことで, 画像表示されてるならインライン表示されたということ)